# Advice needed with EditText fields

Tags: android

Hey guys I am working on android application. My app includes an activity which has two EditText fields. now when this activity starts, the first EditText field should be in focus, and its is only after the user enters some text in that, the other EditText field becomes active that is gets in focus, any idea as how can I do this?I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: /me don't understand how you want to have focus on your EditTexts / what your current state is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If ed1 and ed2 are your two edittexts:
ed2.setEnabled(false);
ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ed2.setEnabled(true);   
    }
});
```

In above code,Unless the user enters something in ed1,ed2 will de disabled. Once the user enters data, it Ibecomes enabled